# Cannot create table VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

When I run this function

```
    Call makeTable("Uber Tracker", range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(LastUber, 42)))
    Call makeTable("Finance Tracker", range(Cells(21, 1), Cells(LastFinance, 23)))
```

The first call works fine, but the second shows error 1004 worksheet range must be on the same sheet as the table being created.

```
    Sub makeTable(TableSheet As String, TableRange As range)
        On Error GoTo errorHandler
        Sheets(TableSheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TableRange, ,xlYes).name = TableSheet

    errorHandler:
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Error number :" + CStr(Err.Number) + " reason: " + Err.Description
        End If

    End Sub
```

What is wrong? I have checked which sheet it is selecting, and it should be correct, same for the range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TableRange is on the ActiveSheet(wherever that is).
You are trying to create a table on sheet ("Finance Tracker") with a range taken from the activesheet.

Depending on what you really need, you can either change the maketable sub like this:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, TableRange, ,xlYes).name = TableSheet
```

Or change the call like this:

```
Call makeTable("Finance Tracker", sheets("Finance Tracker").range(sheet("Finance Tracker").Cells(21, 1), sheet("Finance Tracker").Cells(LastFinance, 23)))
```

Just make sure everything is happening on the same sheet.

**EDIT:**

One more thing to try (works for me this way aswell):

```
Worksheets("Uber Tracker").Activate
Call makeTable("Uber Tracker", Range(Cells(7, 1), Cells(10, 42)))
Worksheets("Finance Tracker").Activate
Call makeTable("Finance Tracker", Range(Cells(21, 1), Cells(30, 23)))
```

Just make sure the Range you use to create a table is on the same sheet where the Table is being added. There are many ways to do this, these are just a few examples.

Comment: so you're saying if I explicitly associate the range with the desired sheet, then it should work?

Comment: tried your activesheet solution, now they both don't work

Comment: mmm... give me a minute. in the mean time, does the other method work?

Comment: Hmm, the Activesheet version works for me. The thing is that the Range you feed to the Table adding method must come from the sheet where you are putting the Table.

Comment: your edit worked, though it's weird because I have tried to activate the worksheet from within the function and that doesn't seem to work

Comment: True, because you select ranges outside of the makeTable Sub. So you'd have to make sure the arguments passed are interpreted on the same sheet too.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use the address of whichever range is passed to the routine:

```
Sheets(TableSheet).ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets(TableSheet).Range(TableRange.Address), ,xlYes).name = TableSheet
```